# Issue with z-index custom kendo alert popup window changing z-index of other popup window

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

In my mvc application, I have grid popup window with code that handles adding descriptions to my forms and it goes like this:

on my grid popup window, click button to open a new popup window to enter description:

```
$("#SendDescription").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
```

the window itself opens correctly, focused, in front of my grid window:

```
<div role="dialog" id="SendDescription" data-role="window">...</div>
```

the window definition:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("SendDescription").Title(Title).Content(@<Text>
<span>@Html.Label("Enter your description here")</span>
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
.Name("MyEditor")
.Tools(tools => tools.Clear())
)
<br />
@(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnSendDescription").SpriteCssClass("classname").Content("Save").Enable(true).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "float:right;" }))

</Text>).Events(e => e.Activate("focusMyEditor")).Actions(action =>      action.Close()).Visible(false).Iframe(true).Modal(false))

function focusMyEditor() {
    $("#MyEditor").data("kendoEditor").focus();
}
```

Whenever validation of a description being saved fails, the MyAlert function gets called:

```
function MyAlert(message) {
    if (!document.getElementById('myAlertDialogBox')) {
        $('body').append('<div id="myAlertDialogBox"><div id="msgd" style="overflow-wrap:break-word; overflow-y:auto"><p id="myAlertMessage"/></div></div>');

        var popup = $("#myAlertDialogBox");

        popup.kendoWindow({
            title: "Title",
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            visible: false,
            height: "100px",
            width: "100px",
            autoFocus: true,
            actions: []

        })
        .data("kendoWindow").center()
        .element.append('<div style="position:absolute; "><input type="button" id="alertclicked" name="alertclicked" value="ok" autofocus></div>');

        $("#alertMsg").text(message);
        $("#alertclicked").bind("click", function () {
            popup.hide(); $(#myAlertDialogBox).data("kendoWindow").close(); $('#myAlertMessage').remove(); $('#myAlertDialogBox').remove();
        });

        $(#myAlertDialogBox).data("kendoWindow").open();;
    }
```

The problem is, when I click 'ok' on 'myAlertDialogBox', the dialog box closes, but my popup window for adding description loses focus and gets 'behind' my grid popup window. I think it happens either due to the alertclicked event or some of my alert popup properties. I tried multiple things in jquery to prevent 'myAlertDialogBox' from loosing focus but had no success at all. Can anyone please suggest what might be wring with the code above? If I use standard Javascript "alert", then 'myAlertDialogBox' stays in front of other windows after clicking 'ok' on 'myAlertDialogBox'. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: When the alert closes, you could call the toFront method on the other popup:  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-toFront

Comment: toFront eventually helped. Thanks! I had to add the following lines:
$("#SendDescription").kendoWindow();
var dialog = $("#SendDescription").data("kendoWindow");
dialog.toFront();